# Finding last occurrence of a particular category within each group and Filter out rows-Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataset as below:

```
data = [[1,'bot', 'a'], [1,'cust', 'b'], [1,'bot', 'c'],[1,'cust', 'd'],[1,'agent', 'e'],[1,'cust', 'f'],
       [2,'bot', 'a'],[2,'cust', 'b'],[2,'bot', 'c'],[2,'bot', 'd'],[2,'agent', 'e'],[2,'cust', 'f'],[2,'agent', 'g'],
       [3,'cust', 'h'],[3,'cust', 'i'],[3,'agent', 'k'],[3,'agent', 'l']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'sender','text'])
df
```

[image]

I want to remove out filter out records under each id group for a specific category(sender). For example, if I want to filter out 'bot' category, I need to find last bot category occurrence under each group(id) and delete records prior to that occurrence.

**Expected output**

[image]

Tried various approaches with groupby functionality but not getting intented output. Any pointers would be quite helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a reverse [`groupby.cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummin.html) for boolean indexing:

```
m = df.loc[::-1,'sender'].ne('bot').groupby(df['id']).cummin()

out = df[m]
```

Output:

```
    id sender text
3    1   cust    d
4    1  agent    e
5    1   cust    f
10   2  agent    e
11   2   cust    f
12   2  agent    g
13   3   cust    h
14   3   cust    i
15   3  agent    k
16   3  agent    l
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway . Was not aware about cummin for boolean indexing